# Issue with Prompts.choice: irrelevant string match if user provide choice as text instead of selecting it from the list of choices provided

Tags: botframework, prompt

While prompting user a list of choices it allow user to either select an option from the list or enter a text value. I know most convenient is to select from the given choices by tab or click on it but if user want to select same option by typing it manually then bot framework returns wrong selected values.

See below example:
[image: Screenshot from attached sample nodeJS application]

It is weird but what I observed is that if there is any number in the text entered and it doesn't completely matches the provided choices it selects the option at that position. For example I entered `cockpit 4` expecting it will match with 3rd option in the list but it actually returns 4th option.

I consider it as bug as its behaviour is not documented and is not working as expected.

I have also created a sample/demo app to show case this issue and since above screenshot is from same app you can try out the example I have mentioned.

Download project from below link:
https://1drv.ms/f/s!AkRT15xJsa0UdY-Y5FPJ8QvY1aU

Comment: The user must enter the complete text of the choice option for it to be properly recognized. In your example, you did not enter the complete option text which would be "Cockpit 4 on level 2 in".  Since you only entered a partial response, which included a number, the recognizer interpreted your input as number based selection. Eg, you picked choice #4.

Comment: I tried both the approaches below:
1. disable the recognition of ordinals
2. improve the score provided by PromptRecognizers.findTopEntity(PromptRecognizers.recognizeChoices(utterance, choices, options));

Second approach is straight forward whereas for the first approach I didn't find any way to just set property like 'recognizeOrdinals'. FYI I am using Prompts.choice and looks like I need to user PromptChoice instead and implement its recognition handlers.
Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is the normal behaviour of PromptChoice as by default it has the following parameters to `true`:

```
/// <param name="recognizeChoices">(Optional) if true, the prompt will attempt to recognize numbers in the users utterance as the index of the choice to return. The default value is "true".</param>
/// <param name="recognizeNumbers">(Optional) if true, the prompt will attempt to recognize ordinals like "the first one" or "the second one" as the index of the choice to return. The default value is "true".</param>
/// <param name="recognizeOrdinals">(Optional) if true, the prompt will attempt to recognize the selected value using the choices themselves. The default value is "true".</param>
```

As a consequence, you can set them to false to avoid having this recognition that you don't want.

You can have a look at the implementation [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/core/src/dialogs/PromptChoice.ts#L127) for Node.js and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L991) for C# as it is open source.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using Prompts.choice so is it possible to set these values without adopting to PromptChoice ?

Comment: Not sure as I'm not using node.js but C#